# MySQl Entity Framework C# Foreign Key Data Load Delay Error

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two Entity classes as follows:

```
public class Stock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string SecId { get; set; }
    public double? LastClearPrice { get; set; } 
    public double? Garant { get; set; }  
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public IList<Position> Positions { get; set; }

}

public class Position
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Stock Stock { get; set; } //virtual for lazy loading
    public int StockId { get; set; }

    public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
    public double OpenPrice { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
    public double? ClosePrice { get; set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }

}
```

I' m making a query like this:

```
    IQueryable<Position> GetAllPositions()
    {
        _context = new StockWatcherContext();
        var getAllPos = _context.Positions.Select(x => x);

        return getAllPos;
    }
```

However the Stock field in the getALlPos object comes back null. Now, that is weird to start with but also when I start debugging and add something like this

var getAllStocks = _context.Stocks.Select(x => x);

After I open up the properties in the debug mode for the getAllStocks object the Stock field for the getAllPos object also gets filled up with data. I have no idea where to move from here and why that happens. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I just see one class and what it seems, half of another class...

Comment: I missed a line when posting this question. Sorry. Fixed it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Stock" property is not marked as virtual (contrary to the comment) so EF's lazy proxy is not in effect. Once you've loaded the Stocks then EF can resolve the stock reference on the previously loaded Position classes.

The same would go for your Positions on the Stock. For lazy loading you need to mark these as virtual so that EF can put in the proxies to manage the call-backs to load them on request. Without virtual, EF will leave them null if it doesn't "know" about them. (eager loaded, or previously loaded into the context.)

Comment: That worked! Also changed the return type of the calling method to List otherwise got an MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Final fixes:

```
public virtual Stock Stock { get; set; }
```

Virtual for lazy loading in the Stock class.

Change the method return type to List.

```
List<Position> GetAllPositions()
    {
        _context = new StockWatcherContext();
        var getAllPos = _context.Positions.Select(x => x).ToList();
        return getAllPos;
    }
```